I'm trying to view the liquid in my glass bottle, but the glass is too reflective
Here is what I'm looking at when I'm in the shader. I have liquid in the bottle but I can't see it. Not sure what I'm missing I tried turning off glossy, flipped normals and some other things but still can't view what's inside the bottle. Rendering it proves to be the same issue as well. Please help!


The image you show is from Material Preview mode, which uses EEVEE to display the scene. If you are using any blender version pre-4.2 and using EEVEE (this includes material preview), you must change the material's Blend Mode to anything other than opaque for tranparency to function. (Scroll down in the material options - Alpha-Blend works fine for most applications)

@ChristopherBennett If this is a "regular" glass material in one way or another like Glass BSDF or Principled BSDF with Transmission, then changing the Blend Mode doesn't help anything, that's for alpha transparency. For transmissive materials Refraction has to be enabled in the material and the render settings. For a pure transmissive material without any faking with transparency the Blend Mode can even be left at Opaque.

I'm using Blender 4.2 and I tried both options but still it doesn't show clear glass. here is a screenshot of when I tried to raytrace. https://postimg.cc/TKZvj4Ry

Here is another screenshot of my material for the glass. https://postimg.cc/NK8kbyt1

I'm also using cycles instead of EEVEE.

Viewport Shading has some improvement but it's still not perfect. This is after changing the blend mode to Alpha Blend. https://postimg.cc/N2w11YnN
